# Side-by-side barplot with line plot overlay in R

Tags: r, plot, line, bar-chart

Ok, I have data in a dataframe, would like to take two variables y1 and y2 and create a side-by-side barplot comparison in which bar height is equal to the value of each element in y1 and y2. Then I want to superimpose a line with the ratio of the two variables, with a second y-axis for these values. My specific problem is that I cannot scale the second y axis appropriately (so in my example reduced the ratio so that it would fall in graph).

More generally, I have a poor understanding of how barcharts work in base graphics and feel like I had to hack my way through it - in spite of reading the multiple posts on this, and a number of tutorials which mostly don't go into enough detail. Some things I am not clear about; A. What is the best way to go from data in a df to data suitable for a barchart - do the data have to be transposed into a barchart matrix as I do here, and why? B. What determines the x-axis placement of the bars (ie what is the "myplot" object and how do the values get determined? Is there a way to set x locations of my points/lines more elegantly? I had to force it using somewhat ugly coding because I don't really understand how it works. C. Not sure about how I would go from row names in my df if I had any, to category (x-axis) names in my bar chart. I sort of had to force this in my plot parameters. D. Is there a definitive discussion about barcharts somewhere that goes into depth a bit more on the inner workings of the bar chart?

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
df <- data.frame(y1 = runif(10, min=0, max=1), y2 = runif(10, min=1, max=2))
df$ratio <- df$y2/df$y1
df

barmatrix <- t(df[,1:2])
barmatrix

par(mfrow = c(1,1))
myplot <- barplot(barmatrix, main="My Barchart", ylab = "Values", ylim = c(0,3), cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.4, beside=TRUE, names.arg=c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"))
lines(x = myplot[1, ] + 0.5, y = df$ratio/3)
points(x = myplot[1, ] + 0.5, y = df$ratio/3)
axis(4, ylim = c(0, 20))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can scale down by 10 to fit on the plot, then scale the numbers (that is, the labels) on your added axis.

```
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
myplot <- barplot(barmatrix, main="My Barchart", ylab = "Values", ylim = c(0,3), cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.4, beside=TRUE, names.arg=c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"))
lines(x = myplot[1, ] + 0.5, y = df$ratio/10)
points(x = myplot[1, ] + 0.5, y = df$ratio/10)
axis(4, at=0:6/2,labels=0:6*5)
```

Update:
to dynamically scale

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
df <- data.frame(y1 = runif(10, min=0, max=1), y2 = runif(10, min=1, max=2))
df$ratio <- df$y2/df$y1
df

barmatrix <- t(df[,1:2])
barmatrix

sf <- max(pretty(df$ratio/3)) # scale factor
# divide by 3 since that is your limit on the barplot ylim
sf

par(mfrow = c(1,1))
myplot <- barplot(barmatrix, main="My Barchart", ylab = "Values", ylim = c(0,3), cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.4, beside=TRUE, names.arg=c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"))
lines(x = myplot[1, ] + 0.5, y = df$ratio/sf)
points(x = myplot[1, ] + 0.5, y = df$ratio/sf)
axis(4, at=0:3,labels=0:3*sf)
```

Update 2: To answer more of your question.
Each row of your matrix `myplot` has the x positions for each series. You can find the average for each column to more flexibly find the midpoint for multiple series.

You can also label with the `row.names` directly.

And with `type="o"` you can plot lines and points at one go.

```
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))
df <- data.frame(y1 = runif(10, min=0, max=1), y2 = runif(10, min=1, max=2))
df$ratio <- df$y2/df$y1

row.names(df) <- LETTERS[1:10]
df
barmatrix <- t(df[,1:2])
barmatrix

sf <- max(pretty(df$ratio/3)) # scale factor
# divide by 3 since that is your limit on the barplot ylim
sf

par(mfrow = c(1,1))
myplot <- barplot(barmatrix, main="My Barchart", ylab = "Values", ylim = c(0,3),
   cex.lab = 1.5, cex.main = 1.4, beside=TRUE, names.arg=row.names(df))
lines(x = colSums(myplot)/nrow(myplot), y = df$ratio/sf,type="o")

axis(4, at=0:3,labels=0:3*sf)
```

Comment: Ah, I see 10 worked for me the first time, but since it is random, it may not always work. If you know the range of `ratio` you can fix it. Otherwise may need to set the scale factor dynamically.